# laravel add to cart with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i am trying to add items to my cart with ajax in laravel but i got error 
419 (unknown status).

here is my ajax code:

```
function btnAddCart(param) {
  var product_id = param;
  var url = "{{ route('cart.add') }}";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { product_id: product_id },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);

    },
    error: function (data) {
      console.log('Error:', data);
    }
  });
};
```

here is my laravel controller function

```
public function addToCart(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->input('product_id'));
    $cart = session()->has('cart') ? session()->get('cart') : [];
    if (array_key_exists($product->id, $cart)) {
        $cart[$product->id]['quantity']++;
    } else {
        $cart[$product->id] = [
            'title' => $product->title,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'unit_price' => $product->sale_price,
        ];
    }
    session(['cart' => $cart]);
    session()->flash('message', $product->title.' added to cart.');

    $data = [];
    $data['cart'] = session()->has('cart') ? session()->get('cart') : [];
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

so now how do i return json data in ajax success function.

Comment: Is there an issue with this code? You say "I got an error", but specifically **what error?** At a glance, the only thing I can see is that `$request->input(1)` should be `$request->input('product_id')`, but otherwise, as long as your PHP works, it should return a JSON response and be available via your success function.

Comment: thx but i get same error.

Comment: Yup; 419 error is because you're not passing a `CSRF` token. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf, and add some logic to pass it or ignore it for API routes.

Comment: Thanks you it works.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the csrf token to your html head section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

After that add this to your js section:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```